# Position element to right of block element

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is there a way using CSS to position an element (block or inline) to the right of a block element without changing the CSS of the block element or of the containing element?

```
<div>Block</div>
<span class="someCSS">Inline</span>
```

Result:

BlockInline

Comment: CSS is for aligning, what else do you want to use if not CSS ? Sounds to me like 'is there a way to eat without a mouth?'

Comment: Of course I'm looking for CSS.  What I'm saying is what CSS would one use to move an element to the right of a block element above it without changing the CSS on the block element itself.  I've updated the question to be more clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well honestly it took me a while till I understood what you wanted, but I think I do now. When you say the inline element is dynamic, you probably use a dynamic language as well, so you could just use some conditional statements to add some css-styling to the inline object.

Another option, depending on your project, might be just to include the span into the block element. And one more would be to wrap the whole thing into two more block elements, so you avoid having a `floating` effect to other following elements.

```
<div style="float:left">
    <div>BLOCK</div>
</div>
<div style="float:right">
    <span>INLINE</span>
</div>
```

Sorry for the inline-css. You got the same effect if you set the inline to `display:block`  if that's possible for you. Or another option to avoid having a `floating` effect to following elements: Use something like `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after everything.

What most people don't know though is that CSS has it's own "conditional statements" already, but up to CSS 4 it won't be possible to select an ancestor directly. But there's no other way (as far as I know) to achieve the wished outcome any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information, the only thing I can suggest is this:

```
element {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: I think that would produce `Inline--------------------------Block`

Answer (score 1):

I would be more inclined to suggest that you do:

```
div { float: left; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/9DCDN/

Comment: This is in fact what I'm currently doing, I'm just curious if there is a way to instead tie the CSS to the latter element as that is the element it's affecting.  Also, the latter element may not always exist and so the float would have to be conditionally added/removed.